# R workspace object properties

Tags: r

Post creation of an R object that is on the workspace, is there any way the check properties which the object does not have implicitly?

Specifically I would like to retrieve the date/time in which one of the objects in the workspace was first created. Is there another approach I could use to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "properties which the object does not have implicitly"?

Comment: @NathanWerth That the object I stored was no built with a property or field containing e.g. the date in which it was created.

Comment: In that case, @oriol-mirosa is correct.  As far as I can tell (reading the official docs for R and its internals), timestamps are not kept for R objects at any level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this for objects that you created in the past. However, when you create an object, you could do this:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
attr(a, 'created') <- Sys.time()

> a
## [1] 1 2 3
## attr(,"created")
## [1] "2017-08-10 09:33:12.000 EDT"
```